# How do I find the temperature measured at 350 hPa?

Tags: geophysics, temperature

1. **You are flying 2.5 km over the ground while your mates are flying up at 350 hPa. All the way between you there are clouds. If you measure that the temperature outside is 4 celsius, what temperature do they measure?**

Don't really know where to start, to be honest. I don't find an equations in my book that seem reasonable to solve this task.

2. **You are in an airplane 2.5 km above the ground. Assume that the atmosphere can be treated as a Standard Atmosphere. The temperature outside is 4 Celsius. You look down toward the ground and see no clouds. What is the expected temperature of the ground?**

Should I just use the adiabatic lapse rate?

Comment: I suggest you ask someone from your course? And - same as here - don't simply ask "what do I do?" but think on the problem, the propose a solution and let them confirm.

Comment: Hint: For a standard atmosphere, what did you learn about temperature lapse rate and about pressure as a function of height?

Comment: I got it now. I was informed in class today that the easiest thing is to use a skew-t chart. I was then able to solve these problems. Thank you both, for your quick respons